# Spring Data and JPA One to many with MapStruct

Tags: spring-data-jpa, mapstruct

I have a one to many relation between Config and ConfigHeaders.
Here is the Config mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {UserMapper.class, ConfigHeadersMapper.class})
public interface ConfigMapper extends EntityMapper<ConfigDTO, Config> {

    @Mapping(source = "user.id", target = "userId")
    ConfigDTO toDto(Config config);

    @Mapping(source = "userId", target = "user")
    @Mapping(target = "messages", ignore = true)
    Config toEntity(ConfigDTO configDTO);

    default Config fromId(Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setId(id);
        return config;
    }
}
```

and here is the ConfigHeadersMapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {ConfigMapper.class})
public interface ConfigHeadersMapper extends EntityMapper<ConfigHeadersDTO, ConfigHeaders> {

    @Mapping(source = "config.id", target = "configId")
    ConfigHeadersDTO toDto(ConfigHeaders configHeaders);

    @Mapping(source = "configId", target = "config")
    ConfigHeaders toEntity(ConfigHeadersDTO configHeadersDTO);

    default ConfigHeaders fromId(Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return null;
        }
        ConfigHeaders configHeaders = new ConfigHeaders();
        configHeaders.setId(id);
        return configHeaders;
    }
}
```

When I try to save a new entity (ids equal to null for the Config & ConfigHeaders) this piece of code:

```
final Config config = configMapper.toEntity(configDTO);
Config newConfig = configRepository.save(config);
```

saves the Config and the ConfigHeaders but the config_id (FK) at the ConfigHeaders is NULL.

So I tried this code:

```
final Config config = configMapper.toEntity(configDTO);
config.getHeaders().stream().forEach(header -> header.setConfig(config));
Config newConfig = configRepository.save(config);
```

and indeed saves the children (ConfigHeaders) with the auto generated parent ID (config_id).

Could you tell me what am I doing wrong with the MapStruct?
I am quite new with this tool and I do not believe this is the correct solution. I consider the previous code only a workaround for now.

Actually I have checked the MapStruct implementation code that have been generated and I have noted that it sets correctly the parent ID (that is null for new ones) but it does not set the backwards relationship with the father entity. How could I accomplish this through MapStruct?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have noticed in order JPA to perform the save correctly you need to set the link to the config in the `ConfigHeader`.

There are 2 ways you can achieve this:

First option:

You can use `CollectionMappingStrategy#ADDER_PREFERRED` (see more [here](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#collection-mapping-strategies)). For this you need to add in your `Config` something like:

```
public void addHeader(ConfigHeader header) {
    this.headers.add(header);
    header.setConfig(this);
}
```

Second option:

You use `@AfterMapping` in your `ConfigMapper` and set the config on all headers there.

```
@AfterMapping
default void linkHeaders(@MappingTarget Config config) {
    config.getHeaders().stream().forEach(header -> header.setConfig(config));
}
```

Third option as proposed by @sjaak in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48974119/1115491:

You can use the `@Context` attribute as shown in the [mapstruct-jpa-child-parent](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-jpa-child-parent) example. This has the same performance as the first option, as you don't have to iterate over the headers twice. The other benefit of this is that you can use it when you can't add stuff to your entities.

It looks like:

```
public class ConfigContext {
    private Config config;
    @BeforeMapping
    public void setConfig(@MappingTarget Config config) {
       this.config = config;
    }

    @AfterMapping
    public void establishRelation(@MappingTarget ConfigHeader header) {
        header.setConfig( header );
    }
}
```

You would also need to adapt your `toEntity` methods so they include the context as well.

Comment: Thank you Filip a lot about your useful input. I used the second approach. Actually I have seen the documentation that you have pointed, but without an example it is not really useful. The paragraph right next to the one that you point provides an example.

Comment: Maybe we need to add the example in the documentation (the adder function is implied for us). If performance is important to you the first approach or the one proposed by sjaak is better, as you are not iterating over the headers twice.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers I really appreciate this. I will use then your first solution.

Comment: I am also trying to do same stuff but I am getting below exception during save -  org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.invenio.loyalty.rewardservice.domain.Item

I am using spring data jpa.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the @Context. This gives you also the possibility to do stuff with the EntityManager. Look [here](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-jpa-child-parent) for an example.

Comment: Thank you for the input. It is possible to solve the problem with your approach as well but Filip's solution seems better to me.

Comment: This approach is actually quite handy and helps when you can't change the entities. It has the same performance as an adder, as it avoids iterating over the headers multiple times